# Выбрать из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет,  интересует как можно  выбрать записи из  двух  таблиц.  Есть  таблица1,  в которой храняться данные о  пользователи и таблица2, в которой  хранятся данные,  которые  пользователь  присылает каждый  день. Как можно  выбирать  записи  кто  не  прислал  ответ сегодня? пробовал  только  такой вариант:

```
SELECT U.* 
  FROM user U
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
      FROM table P
      WHERE P.user_id=U.id AND
            data>='10.02.2019')
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_V2.png

Comment: В принципе запрос написан правильно. Правда дата в каком то странном формате. Если это поле типа date или datetime, то дата обычно задается в формате YYYY-MM-DD. Так же сегодняшняя дата может быть получена функцией curdate()

Comment: Мне кажется вложенные селекты будут выполняться долго при большом количестве записей. Почему не использовать LEFT JOIN ? объединять эти 2 таблицы, для поля U.id добавить distinct, а в where добавить условие IS NULL и сравнение даты, чтобы получить только тех пользователей, для которых не нашлось соответствия во второй таблице. Если ещё и индексацию сделать на нужные поля, то выборка будет выполняться моментально

Comment: Можете  пожалуйста  привести  пример,  не могу  что то  сообразить